# Question about $\cos(x) = 0$ in a restricted domain and arccosine

Tags: trigonometry

In order to solve $\cos(x) = 0$ from $0$ to $2\pi$,  we have to take the $\arccos$ operation on both sides of the equation.

So:

$$x = \arccos(0)$$

According to the range of $\arccos$, $x= \arccos(0)$ is in $[ -\pi/2, \pi/2]$. Based on the range of $arccos$, $x$  is $\pi/2$. So according $arccos$, $\pi/2$ is the solution to $\cos(x) = 0$ from $0$ to $2\pi$.

However, if you draw the cosine graph or use the unit circle, the solution to the $\cos(X) = 0$ from $0$ to $2\pi$ are $\pi/2$ and $3 \pi/2$.

So the cosine graph/unit circle and the arccosine approach give you two different answers.

What is something I am not understanding or I am not getting? Should we use the cosine graph or unit circle to determine the solutions instead of taking the arccosine? Thanks!

Comment: In an equation that you are asked to solve, you are typically given the domain in which your answers should belong.  Use your knowledge of related angles to find the appropriate answers according to the domain.

Comment: Thanks. So it is better to use cosine or unit circle to find the primary answers and not use arccosine?